# Возможно ли вычислить реальный IP?

Tags: proxy, ipv6

Интересует возможность вычислить реальный IP пользователя (когда тот использует прокси IPv6) если у него отключено почти всё (`Flash`, `Java`...). Всё кроме `JS`.

Comment: Боюсь, в текущей формулировке вопрос несколько противоречит кодексу доброго программиста.

Comment: меня интересует лишь возможность вычисления, т.е. существует ли такая при выключенных всех плагинах и т.д.

Comment: Если пользователь использует прокси на всё - откуда же вам знать о его реальном IP? Ну можно конечно, если работать в ФСБ или ФБР, например...

Comment: ну думаю есть способы узнать реальный ип и без органов...

Comment: От присказки с придыханием про фсб чудеса не случатся, и если трафик терминируется на другом айпи - с этим ничего нельзя сделать. А еще вам и не нужен чужой айпи.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Если прокси по настоящему анонимный и человек использует правильное ПО, вы попадаете в настоящий **бесперспективняк** в решении данной проблемы, хотя не анонимные прокси могут прокидывать при запросе различные заголовки типа **X-Forwarded-For** где содержиться реальный IP.

Давайте рассмотрим причины, почему ваши попытки **бесперспективны** при настоящем анонимном Proxy сервере и правильно настроенном ПО:

1. JS - клиентский язык, не имеет доступа к оборудованию, если его не предоставляет сам браузер через технологии и плагины.
2. Прокси-сервер может хранить всю информацию о подключении, но вы ее не получите без разрешения владельца.
3. Есть возможность использовать не просто прокси, а цепочку прокси-серверов расположенных в разных странах, тогда процесс обращения к одному владельцу прокси уже не пройдет.

**Конечным IP всегда является тот, с которого произведен запрос, в данном случае это прокси сервер.**

Получается что реальный IP узнать нельзя, но его можно узнать через различные уязвимости в ПО или программном обеспечении которое хотело сделать этот мир лучше используя весь потенциал технологий, так вот к такому относиться webRTC..**Часто пользователи о ней даже не знают и не подозревают что она включена.**

Есть возможность утащить реальный IP и даже локальный IP через утечку адреса в технологии webRTC (**webRTC ip leak**), если пользователь не отключил у себя ее в браузере или имеет клиентское ПО поддерживающее данный протокол.

> Технология WebRTC была создана разработчиками Google для быстрой
>   передачи и защиты конфиденциальной информации с использованием
>   браузера, не устанавливая никаких дополнительных программ и
>   расширений.

Демонстрация работы утечки скрытого IP продемонстрирована на [проекте в Github](https://diafygi.github.io/webrtc-ips/)

Comment: если здесь https://diafygi.github.io/webrtc-ips/ ничего не показывает, тогда никто ничего не узнает?

Comment: @emtecif Вероятнее всего нет, если нет других способов утечки данных, а через JS больше известных мне способов нет :)

Comment: а через что можно узнать параметры оборудования? флеш?

Comment: `webRTC` - это единственное через что может утечь реальный IP? Вы говорите что `webRTC` придумали в Google, получается есть шанс что сами Google даже при выключенной функции `webRTC` смогут узнать настоящий IP пользователя, или такая возможно исключена?

Comment: @emtecif не, это вряд ли. Возможность утекания адреса через включенный WebRTC существует из-за STUN, два соединяющихся клиента обмениваются всеми известными им собственными адресами (через сервер-сигналку), добавляют пару эвристических вариантов и пробуют соединиться друг с другом через каждый из них. Если выключить WebRTC, STUN не будет задействован и обмена адресами не будет.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю что на этот вопрос вы не найдёте ответ сдесь, поищите [тут](https://security.stackexchange.com/search?q=track%20ip%20adress)
!

В принципе дело практики и знание технологий, которые позволяют находить "дыры" или как выше сказанное "утечки".

Советую найти книги про сетевые протоколы, таких пално. Сначало надо понимать саму работу IP протокола, потом его отслеживать.

Но при использовании нескольких VPN как цепочку, навряд ли удастся отследить без согласия поставшика IP адресса и сериозной программы. Вообше дело сериозное пробуйте на cyber форумах как по ссылке выше.